# Building a C# app with Visual Studio online to S3

Tags: visual-studio, aws-code-deploy

We have some Visual Studio 2015 projects on GitHub. We also want to use Visual Studio online for build. Our products will be hosted on AWS so I am thinking of using Code Deploy to deploy the products to AWS. As you may already know code deploy can pick up the artifacts from S3 and deploy them.

I have managed to set up my build in Visual Studio online. The code is fetched from git and is built perfectly. However the artifacts are copied into an online folder and then I have to download them.  Is there a way to copy the artifacts to S3 instead? So from there I can use Amazon CodeDeploy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If your app is not very big and you are not going to build more than 100 tasks every month, probably you can try Zapier. They support connection for different services, like S3 and Visual Studio.
  https://zapier.com/zapbook/amazon-s3/visual-studio-online/
- Or maybe you can write up a script to do the work yourself. I'm not quite sure about how VS build works, but for AWS, you can easily install aws cli to upload an artifact from local directory to a s3 bucket, after downloading it from VS build online.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code https://github.com/AmyrisTech/vso-tasks to create a task in VSO to upload files to AWS S3 (in case a zip file).
I didn't find any way to call CodeDeploy from VSO yet.